# Edit and Del link

Tags: visualforce, google-apps

I have google visualization table on a visualforce page.For this I need to edit and delete link to the record.Edit link should redirect to the record edit page and delete link should delete the record.Can someone help me.

```
<apex:page Controller="SController">
<style>
    .chartHidden{
        display: none;
    }
    .chartShown{
        display: block;
    }
</style>
 <style type='text/css'>
  .bold-green-font {
   font-weight: bold;
   color: green;
   }

   .bold-font {
   font-weight: bold;
    }

  .right-text {
   text-align: right;
    }

  .orange-background {
   background-color: orange;
  }

   .beige-background {
    background-color: beige;
  }

 </style>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi' />
<script src="/soap/ajax/19.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript" />

 <script type="text/javascript">

  // use this function to format the label
  formatCurrencyLabel = function( value )
 {
  return "$" + String(value);
  }

 google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['table', 'corechart']});
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);
 function SetGranteeID(str, value) {
 document.getElementById("GranteeID").value = document.getElementById(str + '_lkid').value
 document.getElementById("GranteeName").value = value;
 }
function drawTable() {

  // Create a new data table with two columns: the label and the value
     var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
     // We need the sessionId to be able to query data
     sforce.connection.sessionId = '{!$Api.Session_ID}';
     // Query data using SOQL.

        data.addColumn('string', 'Grantor');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Grantee');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Budget(Expenses)');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Amount');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Record Type');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Funding Level');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Fiscal Year');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Start of Period');
        data.addColumn('string', 'End of Period');

        var result = sforce.connection.query("SELECT id, grantor__r.name GRANTOR, " +
        "grantee__r.name GRANTEE,sum(Budget_Expenses__c) BUDGET, Sum(Amount__c) AMOUNT, " +
        "funding_type__c TYPE, Funding_Level__c LEVEL, Fiscal_Year__c FY, Start_of_Period__c SOP, " +
        "End_of_Period__c EOP " + 
        "FROM Funding_Event__c " +
        "where series__c = '{!seriesid}' " +
        "group by id, grantor__r.name, grantee__r.name, funding_type__c, Funding_Level__c, " +
        "Fiscal_Year__c, Start_of_Period__c, End_of_Period__c");

        // Iterate over the result
        var it = new sforce.QueryResultIterator(result);
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            var record = it.next();
            // Add the data to the table

            data.addRow([record.GRANTOR, record.GRANTEE, {v:parseFloat(record.BUDGET), f: formatCurrencyLabel(record.BUDGET)}, {v:parseFloat(record.AMOUNT), f: formatCurrencyLabel(record.AMOUNT)}, record.TYPE, record.LEVEL, record.FY, record.SOP, record.EOP]);

        }



   var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({negativeColor: 'red', negativeParens: true, pattern: '$###,###'});

   formatter.format(data, 2);
   formatter.format(data, 3);

  var formatter_short = new google.visualization.DateFormat({formatType: 'short'});
  formatter.format(data, 7);
   formatter.format(data, 8);

 var table2 = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('tblFEHistory'));
  table2.draw(data, {width: 1000, allowHtml: true});
  }
 </script>
 <apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock title="Funding Event History View" mode="edit">
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
           <div id="tblFEHistory"></div>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
 </apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Can you provide some more information on your question? I am not really sure what you are asking. What have you tried so far? What isn't working exactly?

Comment: @Jesse Altman I have added image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added column called Action and then updated row in while loop

```
data.addColumn('string', 'Action');



data.addRow(['<a href="/' + record.ID + '/e?retURL=/{!seriesid}" target="_parent">Edit</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="/setup/own/deleteredirect.jsp?delID=' + record.ID + '&retURL=/{!seriesid}" target="_parent">Del</a>',..
```

Comment: can you please provide some sample code for how exactly you have implemented this data.addcolumn in vFpage.

Answer (score 6):

Edit would be easy, it's just `{object id}/e`. Delete is trickier as it requires calling `deleteredirect.jsp` and passing confirmation token...

What you need is an [`URLFOR`](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm#URLFOR) function call. These might help too:

- http://salesforcesource.blogspot.com/2008/12/urlfor-function-finally-explained.html
- www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_dynamic_vf_globals_action.htm
- http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_action_valid_values.htm

So, something like this should help:

```
{!URLFOR($Action.Funding_Event__c.delete, record.id)}
```

(you'd still have to add new column for it and include this "field" in the `while` loop).

Comment: Thanks @eyescream.Can you please let me know how to add column and add row in while loop.

Comment: I have added addrow as  data.addRow(['<a href="/record.ID">Edit</a>',record.GRANTOR,...) But edit link points to    https://c.cs10.visual.force.com/record.Id

Comment: `record` is a javascript variable in your case so you need string concatenation for example, something like `data.addRow(['<a href="/' + record.Id + '/e">Edit</a>', record.GRANTOR,...)`. If you'll be getting nulls in the `record.Id` expression - maybe put an alias in the query: `SELECT Id id, grantor__r.name GRANTOR ...` because by default I think it'll get the generic `expr0` as the column name.